# Can I use Stipe api without using Stripe Card Element

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am creating dynamic payment module using stripe in that while I am doing it with Stripe elements it is working fine but when I use Input and provide data it is not working. so I need to ask is there any way that I can use Input tag and still can call API. and if not can someone please give me official link that says so. I am not able to find it.

This is my code with Input tags

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="name">Full Name</label>
      <input
        id="name"
        required
        placeholder="Jenny Rosen"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setName(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <br />
      <label htmlFor="cardNumber">Card Number</label>
      <input
        value={CardNumber}
        maxLength={16}
        onChange={(e) => {
          e.target.value = e.target.value
            .replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "")
            .replace(/(\..*)\./g, "$1");
          setCardNumber(e.target.value);
        }}
        type="text"
        id="cardNumber"
        options={ELEMENT_OPTIONS}
      />
      <br />
      <label htmlFor="expiry">Card Expiration Month</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={CardExpiryMonth}
        maxLength={2}
        onChange={(e) => {
          e.target.value = e.target.value
            .replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "")
            .replace(/(\..*)\./g, "$1");
          setCardExpiryMonth(e.target.value);
        }}
        id="expiry"
        options={ELEMENT_OPTIONS}
      />
      <br />
      <label htmlFor="expiry">Card Expiration Year</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={CardExpiryYear}
        maxLength={4}
        onChange={(e) => {
          e.target.value = e.target.value
            .replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "")
            .replace(/(\..*)\./g, "$1");
          setCardExpiryYear(e.target.value);
        }}
        id="expiry"
        options={ELEMENT_OPTIONS}
      />
      <br />
      <label htmlFor="cvc">CVC</label>
      <input
        value={CardCVV}
        maxLength={3}
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => {
          e.target.value = e.target.value
            .replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "")
            .replace(/(\..*)\./g, "$1");
          setCardCVV(e.target.value);
        }}
        id="cvc"
        options={ELEMENT_OPTIONS}
      />
      <br />
      <label htmlFor="postal">Postal Code</label>
      <input
        id="postal"
        required
        placeholder="12345"
        value={postal}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setPostal(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <br />
      <label htmlFor="postal">User Name</label>
      <input
        required
        placeholder="user name"
        value={username}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setUsername(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <br />
      <label htmlFor="postal">Address</label>
      <input
        required
        placeholder="address"
        value={address}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setAddress(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      {errorMessage && <ErrorResult data={errorMessage} />}
      {paymentMethod && (
        <Result data={"Got Payment Success: " + paymentMethod}></Result>
      )}
      <button type="submit" disabled={!stripe}>
        Pay
      </button>
    </form>
```

and this is how I am calling the API

```
const body = { amount: 600, email: "a@gmail.com" };
    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };
    let options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    };
    const secretKey = await fetch(
      "https://f8d5-45-125-156-6.ngrok.io" + "/api/v1/stripeCheckOut",
      options
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(async (res) => {
        console.log("CHECKOUT_RES", res);
        return res.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("CHECKOUT_error", error);
        return error;
      });

    console.log("CARDBODY", {
      number: CardNumber,
      exp_month: parseInt(CardExpiryMonth),
      exp_year: parseInt(CardExpiryYear),
      cvc: CardCVV,
    });

    // const token = await stripe
    //   .createToken({
    //     card: {
    //       number: CardNumber,
    //       exp_month: CardExpiryMonth,
    //       exp_year: CardExpiryYear,
    //       cvc: CardCVV,
    //     },
    //   })
    //   .then((response) => console.log("TOKEN", response));

    const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(secretKey, {
      payment_method: {
        type: "card",
        card: {
          number: CardNumber,
          exp_month: CardExpiryMonth,
          exp_year: CardExpiryYear,
          cvc: CardCVV,
        },
        billing_details: {
          name: username,
          email: "codentic.user@gmail.com",
          phone: 8460304001,
          address: {
            line1: address,
            postal_code: postal,
          },
        },
      },
    });
    console.log("PaymentMethod", JSON.stringify(payload));
    if (payload.error) {
    } else {
      checkStatus(payload.paymentIntent.id);
      // setPaymentMethod(payload.paymentMethod);
    }
```

if I Use this in card

```
  const card = elements.getElement(CardNumberElement);

    if (card == null) {
      return;
    }
```

it is working fine. please help

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass raw card details to the confirmCardPayment function..  It’s also worth noting that if you do find and build an approach where you are handling raw card data, then this will shift the PCI compliance burden onto you and your team. [0](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance)